# Control not available in vb. Net winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm working with an old project of vb. Net., created in 3.5 framework .
There  a  datetime picker Control.

[image]

But,  now I have dropped  this  control again, but I didn't find this. Control with 4.0,

The year, it has Up/Down arrow.

I want to  get  focused the year selection when I click  drop down. 
As you  can  see October 2015
When I select  2015 it shows up down arrow to increase /decrease  years.

Help me to  figure out,  how may I find the  event,  which selects/focus this year control when control shown.

I am modifying this question clearing more the required functionality.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to select Year only?

Comment: Behavior of `DateTimePicker` depends on OS.

Comment: No, this control is fine but I'm saying, inside this control, if we click with mouse over the value "2015" User Interface gets changed and I can see up-down arrow to manipulate the year value,what  I want, is that, instead of clicking , when I click on datetime picker Control, through code I force to get focused on the year area so the user can see, there is an option too to navigate between years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that behavior of `DateTimePicker` depends on OS, If you want to select year only, you can do this in designer or code:

- Set `Format` to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`;
- Set `CustomFormat` to `yyyy`;
- Set `ShowUpDown` to `true`;

[image]

**EDIT**

We can simulate click on year part programmatically but it will behave differently on different OS that is not desired.

But here is the main idea that may be useful for such cases.

In this code we move cursor to suitable location an perform a click using code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

public void PerformClick()
{
    uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
    uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}

//Don't forget to attach handler to DropDown event of your `DatePicker`
private void dateTimePicker1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //wait to dropdown show
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    //Calculate the point that you want to click
    //Change 125 and 5 to tune the location.
    var p = new Point(
        this.dateTimePicker1.Location.X + 125,
        this.dateTimePicker1.Location.Y + this.dateTimePicker1.Height + 5
        );

    Cursor.Position = this.PointToScreen(p);
    PerformClick();
}
```

And here is the result on my system:

[image]

Comment: @DareDevil Yes I see it now:) You should know behavior of `DateTimePicker` depends on OS and for example in Windows 8 if you click on year `DateTimePicker` behave differently and shows a list of monthes for you. So While I think we can simulate click on year programmatically but it will behave differently on different OS that is not desired.

Comment: @DareDevil as an advice, when you want to do a job in a way that you have not ever seen, you should think about it again.

Comment: @DareDevil Check the edit, hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: @DareDevil don't forget to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: Buddy, Did you revise my UI attached? I have set all the option to a control but I am unable to find these settings, the Look like interface in the Screen Shots, I did with your said method but I can only see the month Selected, where I have to select only the year

Comment: @DareDevil Above codes perform a click on year part of DateTimePicker, but in my system (WIndows 8.1) when I click on year I see list of month. What is your OS?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92250/discussion-between-daredevil-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: @DareDevil Are those screenhots taken from execution in windows 8.1?  Here in my system (Windows 8.1), when I click on year I see list of month. My screenshot is taken from execution on windows 8.1.

Comment: @DareDevil The main idea is what I post as Edit and this way you can simulate a mouse event on your `DateTimePicker`. You can change codes and use theme where you need. Hope you find the descriptions and codes helpful and acceptable. That was the best thing that I could do for you:)

Comment: @DareDevil by the way, think about my advice :)